# How can I build multiple step selectors in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contact-form

I have a problem with HTML contact form. 
For example I have that schema with element dependencies:

[image]

Where are many selectors and inputs depends on what is selected in previous steps.

How can I build that logic in HTML and Javascript (Jquery)?

For result I need to return one input hidden field, where are placed all selected values, for example:

Cash - at Compensa partners - Outside Riga - Serviss from selected option

Maybe there are some Jquery solutions for that purpose?

P.S. I can only use HTML pages

Comment: What have you tried so far and where does it throw an error? SO tries to fix errors in your code, not write your code for you.

Comment: I didn't ask for writing all code for me. I only want examples how to do that with jquery or something like that. I tried with show, hide, and change attr('name'), but it's too hard to build all dependencies with that method.

Comment: You either write all the different options out and only show the correct branch, or you create a map that has all these branches and dynamically edit the options of a couple of <select> tags.

Comment: Maybe you can send some links with examples?

Comment: @AlexIL That's not the way StackOverflow works. There are many ways to solve your problem, the question is too broad. SO is for questions on code you have written but is not working, not for suggestions. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example: write out all the different selects and only show the relevant one. You can add all the other dependencies in a similar way. Building the selects dynamically will be less, but more complicated code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
        .show {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="claim">
        <select>
            <option value="default" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a claim type</option>
            <option value="cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="repair">Repair</option>
            <option value="glazing">Glazing</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="cash" class="hide">
        <select>
            <option value="partners">At Compensa partners</option>
            <option value="office">Compensa Office</option>
            <option value="broken">Verhicle is broken</option>
        </select>       
    </div>
    <div id="repair" class="hide">
        <select>
            <option value="age">Car age</option>
            <option value="place">Serviss place</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
    <script>
        var dependencies = {
            'claim' : {
                'cash' : 'nextDep',
                'repair' : 'nextDep',
                'glazing' : 'nextDep'
            }
        };
        document.querySelector('#claim select').addEventListener('change', function ( event ) {
            var parentID = event.target.parentNode.id,
                value = event.target.value;
            Object.keys(dependencies[parentID]).forEach(function ( key ) {
                var select = document.querySelector('#' + key),
                    currentClass = select.className;
                if (select.id === value && currentClass === 'hide') select.className = 'show';
                else if (currentClass !== 'hide') select.className = 'hide';
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```